# Use restricted area start and restricted area end in two different custom flowcharts

Tags: anylogic

I have 2 custom flowcharts where restricted area start is in Agent Type "Buy" and restricted area end is in Agent Type "Sold". If I try to get the connection of restricted area end and restricted area start in the restricted area end block by "Buy.restrictedarea" it says Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field"

[image: main]

[image: restrictedareaend]

[image: parameter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buy is your agent class, and to do what you want you need a single agent buy or a population of agents buys

then you will be able to do buy.restrictedarea

If you are using a custom flowchart, it means that you have an instance of the class Buy somewhere (called buy probably with no capital letters)

Comment: I have an agent population in Main where I have the element chooser of my parameter with the Type: RestrictedAreaStart where I thought I could do Buy.restrictedarea but then there is the error Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field".

Comment: I attached a screenshot. In main I called in my agent population in the element chooser Buy.restrictedAreaStart, also tried with buy.RestrictedAreaStart

Comment: I found the problem. I have to call the name of the agent population and not the name of the agent itself